# php file upload using example (not working)

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I trying learn php file upload. I playing with w3school examples and my script not understand variable file:

```
<form method="post" action="script.php" >
<table class="usertable">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="file_upload" name="file" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and php script (from w3school):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
   } else {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
     if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
     } else {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     }
   }
 } else {
   echo "Invalid file";
 }
```

When script running he return same errors: Notice: `Undefined index: file in`. But if i understand variable 'file' is input field name?

Comment: Many scripts on w3schools are buggy and full of bad practice, try using official docs examples from [php.net](http://php.net).

Comment: In your `<form>`, enctype is missing: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use *enctype* to upload files

```
<form method="post" action="script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```